# How do I select an inactive field in Watir?

Tags: html, ruby, automation, watir

My page has a popup that becomes visible when you click on a button.

Although I can manually manipulate the fields on the popup when it is visible, when I inspect any of the fields, they're showing up "grayed out" / inactive in firebug.

This didn't used to be the case, and since it's started happening, I'm unable to use Watir to select any of the fields on the popup.

How do I get around this?

The HTML is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsz5.jpg)

I need to set the checkbox that you see near the bottom of that code in blue highlighting.

I used to select it with:
        `$browser.table(:id => "productSelectTable")[1][0].click`

but now that all of the HTML above is showing up as grayed out when I inspect it, that doesn't work any more.

Comment: What changed between the time it worked and did not work? Is there any error message from Watir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$browser.td(:class, "tableCell centerCell).hidden.click